# How to access row value from UPDATE sub query function?

Tags: postgresql, update, subquery

I would need to use `UPDATE` like this:

```
update offer set (bank, bank_id) = (cost, gid)
from (
select cost, osm_points.gid from pgr_kdijkstraCost(
  'SELECT gid as id, source, target, walk_cost as cost FROM ways',
  offer.vertice_id,
  array(select vertice_id from osm_points where super_type = 'bank'),
  false,false)
join osm_points on id2 = vertice_id
where cost != -1
and osm_points.super_type = 'bank'
order by cost
limit 1)t ;
```

but I get following:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "offer"
>
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "offer", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state that. I use PostgSQL 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and @Daniel's suggestions I came to following solution I need define my own type and use it to extract data from subquery:

```
create type closest_poi as (cost float, poi_gid bigint);
with closest as (
select
  distinct o.gid,
  ((select row(cost,gid)
  from pgr_kdijkstraCost(
    'SELECT gid as id, source, target, walk_cost as cost FROM ways',
    o.vertice_id,
    array(select vertice_id
          from osm_points
          where super_type = 'kindergarden'),
    false,false)
  join osm_points on id2 = vertice_id
  where cost != -1
  and super_type = 'kindergarden'
  order by cost
  limit 1)::text::closest_poi).*
from offer o, osm_points p
where p.super_type = 'kindergarden'
and st_dwithin(o.the_geom::geography,p.the_geom::geography,5000)
order by 1)

update offer 
set 
  kindergarden = closest.cost,
  kindergarden_id = closest.poi_gid
from closest
where offer.gid = closest.gid;
```

Answer (score 5):

When using a query of this form: `UPDATE a SET columns=values FROM b WHERE ...`, the `b` subquery is evaluated independently of `a`, and it's the WHERE block at the end of the query that is supposed to join the rows of `a` and `b`.

The query in the question attempts to join inside the subquery rather than in a WHERE clause at the uppermost level (in fact it doesn't have such a WHERE clause), but it's not allowed and that's what the error message indicates.

The SQL-standard way of updating each row with a correlated subquery would be:

```
UPDATE a SET (col1,col2) =
   (SELECT val1,val2 FROM b WHERE expression-needing-values-from-a)
```

but in older versions of PostgreSQL (9.4 or before), [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-update.html#AEN86100) explicitly tells that this form is **not implemented**. Starting with 9.5, it is implemented.

The typical way to emulate it with postgres 9.4 is to use a copy of table `a` in the subquery and join back to the updated table in the upper level's WHERE clause, like this:

```
 UPDATE a SET (col1,col2)=(s.col1,s.col2)
  FROM (SELECT a2.ctid,col1,col2 AS ctid_of_row FROM b, a AS a2 WHERE...) AS s
   WHERE s.ctid_of_row = a.ctid;
```

knowing that `ctid` is the [system pseudo-column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) that indicates the *physical location of the row version within its table*. Alternatively, the primary key can be used if there is one.

In your case, the transformation is not obvious because your subquery is meant to produce only one row with its `ORDER BY... LIMIT 1` at the end. It should be redesigned to produce all the target rows in a single resultset, presumably `(verticeid,cost,gid)` where `cost` and `gid` are determined per `offer.verticeid`.

Comment: Probem is that I need to pass value of vertice_id from current row to the function pgr_kdjistracost this function returns multiple records and I need one with minimal cost

Comment: @Milan: you can write something along the lines of `select vertice_id, (select ... from pgr_kdjistracost(...) join... where ... order by cost limit 1) as s from offer`.

Comment: Of note, the SQL-standard way (using a correlated subquery) became supported in PostgreSQL 9.5